# What does the word full mean to do in this piece

Tags: notation, flute

I was trying to play the song Legends Never Die for flute and I found the word full on an arrow attached to a note and do now know what it means or how to play it.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is guitar part, not flute, right? In guitar notation "full" means to bend note by a whole tone, in this case from A to B. I'm not sure if you can recreate this exact effect of flute; perhaps you can simply play B on the last beat. Maybe you can play a half bend A#-B, if you can? Or glissando A-A#-B? Whatever sounds the best.